# calling a function with require but variables and arrays are undefined

Tags: php, arrays, variables, scope, require

Why aren't my variable seen when called with require ?

**function.php**

```
<?php
function paginator(){

    $links  = array("index.php", "services.php", "content.php","contact_us.php" );
    $trimslug = substr(strrchr($_SERVER['PHP_SELF'], "/"), 1); 

        foreach ($links as $key => $value) {
            if ($value == $trimslug ) {
                $GLOBALS['$page'] = $key;
            }
        }
    $page = $GLOBALS['$page'];
    $next = $page+1;
    $previous = $page-1;
}



?>
```

**content.php**

```
<?php
session_start();
require './functions.php';
paginator();
?>


<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Pagination</title>
</head>
<body>

<h2>Now on Page : <?php echo $page?></h2>

<a href="<?php echo $links[$next] ?>" >Next</a>
<br><br><br>

<a href="<?php  echo $links[$previous]?>" >Previous</a>
<br>


</body>
</html>
```

I would like to be able to see my variables, when using the require function as this piece of code will be on every page. This might be a very noobish concept to grasp but I would really like someone to illustrate the concept properly.

This seemed to work, Thank you everyone.

```
<?php

    $links  = array("index.php", "services.php", "content.php","contact_us.php" );
    $trimslug = substr(strrchr($_SERVER['PHP_SELF'], "/"), 1); 
    $page = null;

    function paginator(){
    global $links,$trimslug,$next,$previous,$page;

        foreach ($links as $key => $value) {
        if ($value == $trimslug ) {
            // $GLOBALS['$page'] = $key;
            $page = $key;
        }
    }
$next = $page+1;
$previous = $page-1;
}

?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The variables inside paginator are only in the scope of the function, not the php file. If you want to access them outside that function, just move those variables outside of it. Eg

```
$page=null;
$links=...
function paginator(){
...
}
```

Comment: I tried that ... I'm very confused at this point ... if I name all my variables outside the scope of the function, what would be left inside the function ?

Comment: the key concept is that variables that are in defined inside a function are lost once the function call ends. defining them outside the function (or global) makes them available within your function.php, the paginator function, and also content.php. the "require" command basically merges function.php and content.php.

Answer (score 0):

This is because the variables are defined in the scope of the function paginator();

If you want them to be accesible in the scope of content.php, either declare them like this:

```
global $variable = 'value';
```

Or, just declare them in function.php without the need of the function & it's subsequent call in content.php.

Comment: the code works if it's not in a function. but in order to be a little cleaner, I tried to make it a function and now i have issue...For some reason I still can't understand this concept. If i call the require page (function.php) and then call the function within the first few lines, it should go through the program and works as if it wasn't function call ... no ? I even tried to return $page .... that's didn't work either ... I'm missing a key concept here !

Comment: How do you become cleaner by using the function. I don't see the point.

Stil, if you want to achieve it with the function, use the global keyword as suggested.

Comment: I would like to thank you as well for being part of the answer ! But i can only thank one person.

Comment: That's OK. Either ways, the solutions are effectively the same. Using the global keyword specifies that the scope is global & predefining the variables with NULL also does the same thing effectively. In fact, it is easier to maintain if you use global, because you do not have to go and predefine each new variable you may use in the future. Regarding understanding as mentioned in your earlier comment check http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php

Answer (score 0):

Variables in PHP are limited to the scope of the function, unless called via an argument or by adding to the global array.

Global arrays are bad practice, just sayin.

You could always make the variables into a private class and call it as needed, though that's pretty tricky for beginners.

Comment: why is it bad to have global variables ? As you could see i'm using $GLOBALS['$page'] in my function to retain the value of $key ? Is there a better way ? Are they security risks when using the globals array ?

Comment: Yup. Although it comes down to sanitizing user input data, having things in global can create a security loophole, especially if there is an error being printed. Passing as arguments [i.e.`function myFunction($argument)`] is a little safer. Or that's what I've been told, at least.